# Unity: Car Rollover Protection

Tags: unity, car

I have a standart Unity car with Unity Car physics.
What would be the best approach to protect my car from a rollover?

I dont want to mess up and try and error 10 different approaches, so maybe here is an expert who really knows how to do it right?

I couldnt find anything decent on the internet.

Comment: Could you clarify which dimensions the car is rolling in? A screenshot with the transform axes displayed could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally use [AddRelativeTorque](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque.html).
In its simplest form, flip the car on its Z axis when the car is upside down.

```
RigidBody RB = ...;
float flipStrength = 1f;

if (Mathf.Abs(transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.z) > 90f) {
    RB.AddRelativeTorque(0f, 0f, flipStrength, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: Just lock the x and z axis of the rigidbody.  Now the car will always stay horizontal. But it also will have difficulties with ramps.